# Exercise with Dense subset.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Topological Space. Let $D\subset X$ be a dense subset. Prove that $\forall\mathcal{U}\in\tau$, $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\overline{\mathcal U\cap D}$

I know that since $D$ is dense, $D\cap \mathcal{U}\neq\emptyset$, $\forall\mathcal{U}\in\tau$. But honestly I don't know how to proceed. I though that, if $x\in\mathcal{U} - \overline{\mathcal{U}\cap D}$ then there is a closed subset $C$ such that $x\notin C\supseteq\overline{\mathcal{U}\cap D}$, but maybe this fact is useless. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x\in \mathcal U$ (if $\mathcal U=\emptyset$ the result is trivially true). If $x\in D$ then $x\in \mathcal U\cap D$, so $x\in\overline{\mathcal U\cap D}$ (since a set is contained in its closure). If $x\notin D$ consider any $V\in\tau$ such that $x\in V$. Then we have that $x\in\mathcal U\cap V$ and $\mathcal U\cap V\in\tau$, so $V\cap(\mathcal U\cap D)=(\mathcal U\cap V)\cap D\neq\emptyset$, since $D$ is dense and $\mathcal U\cap V\in\tau$. We have that for any open set containing $x$, its intersection with $\mathcal U\cap D$ is nonempty, so $x\in\overline{\mathcal U\cap D}$ by the definition of closure or by the equivalence of the definition with this local definition. Therefore $\mathcal U\subset\overline{\mathcal U\cap D}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $U = \varnothing$ then we obviously have $U \subseteq \overline{U \cap D}$. If $U \neq \varnothing$ then take $x \in U$ and keep in mind that we want to prove that $x \in \overline{U \cap D}$, that is, we want to prove that for all $V \in \tau$ with $x \in V$ we have $V \cap (U \cap D) \neq \varnothing$. To do this, fix $V \in \tau$ such that $x \in V$. Then observe that $V \cap U$ is a non-empty element of $\tau$, and then, since $D$ is dense, we have $(V \cap U) \cap D \neq \varnothing$!

Comment: @Darsen Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be a comment on my answer directed to the OP!

Comment: @Darsen your poof is clear too me thank you